# How to obtain second level domains under the ".uk" ccTLD

Tags: java, networking, dns

I have the ".uk" ccTLD. I want to retrieve the list of all second level domains under it. I tried using a StringBuilder that contains different combinations and lengths of alphabets(for example aa.uk-zz.uk, aaa.uk-zzz.uk)[**code is listed below**]. To test it, I initially planned to use the **Whois** class. But after couple of tests, I obtain "quota exceeded" as a reply. So I discarded this possibility since each IP address is given a certain limit. Is it possible to access and retrieve the list of second level domains of the DNS name server? If so, please instruct me how to do it in java.

`

public class generateDomain {

```
public static void genDomain(int iDomainLength, String sPredecessor,int iSubLevel) {

    //===========DECLARATIONS==============
    char[] arr_charAlphabets;
    String sDiffcombinations="";
    int[] arr_iPosition;
    int iTotalPossibilities;
    StringBuilder sBuilderComb;
    //==========END OF DECLARATIONS========


    //===========START OF ARRAY BUILDER===================
    //Build an array of characters storing all alphabets
    //a(97)-z(122) - lowercase only
    arr_charAlphabets = new char[26];
    for(int iIterator=97;iIterator<=122;iIterator++){
        arr_charAlphabets[iIterator-97] = (char) iIterator;
    }
    //===========END OF ARRAY BUILDER======================

    //===========START OF TEMPLATE BUILDER=================
    //This portion builds a template of <spaces> and
    //these <spaces> will be replaced with alphabets
    for(int iIterator=1;iIterator<=iDomainLength;iIterator++){
        sDiffcombinations+=" ";
    }
    //===========END OF TEMPLATE BUILDER===================
    sBuilderComb = new StringBuilder(sDiffcombinations);

    arr_iPosition = new int[iDomainLength];
    iTotalPossibilities = (int) Math.pow(26, iDomainLength);


    for (int iIterator1 = 0; iIterator1 < iTotalPossibilities; iIterator1++){

        for (int iIterator2 = 0; iIterator2 < iDomainLength; iIterator2++){

            if (arr_iPosition[iIterator2] == arr_charAlphabets.length){
                arr_iPosition[iIterator2] = 0;
                if (iIterator2 + 1 < iDomainLength) {
                    arr_iPosition[iIterator2 + 1]++;
                }
            }

            sBuilderComb.setCharAt(iIterator2, arr_charAlphabets[arr_iPosition[iIterator2]]);
        }

        arr_iPosition[0]++;
        //======================================================
        System.out.println(sBuilderComb.toString()+sPredecessor);

    }


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    genDomain(2, ".uk", 1);
    System.out.println("Combinations of length 2 generated");
}
```

}

`

Comment: Just one question for now - why?

Comment: it's for a project at the university

Comment: please see this http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23786/is-it-possible-to-find-all-subdomains-for-a-certain-domain

Comment: I also think you can do a web crawler to get a list of .uk subdomains, generating domains doesn't seem like a viable option as there are dozens of them

Comment: @BorysZibrov does the web crawler guarantees that all second level domains will be discovered?

Comment: no, of course not, but I think it will be pretty good, and the longer you crawl, the better the results will be

Comment: @BorysZibrov Ahh okay. I need to discover all the second level domains.

Answer (score 0):

First, trying to brute-force all names in a zone is a highly antisocial act that will get you blacklisted. Stop trying at once.

Second, you say that you're doing this for a university project. In that case, you should *really* learn how DNS works before you write another character of source code. Learning is why you're at university in the first place, right?

Third, the right way to get someone else's information is not to try to rip it from them against their will (as you are doing now). The right way is to ask them nicely to give it to you, and be prepared that they may require compensation in order to give it to you. "Them" in the case of the `UK` ccTLD is [Nominet](http://www.nominet.uk). All the information you need to answer your question here is available on their web site.